# How to prevent the "BUTTON LINK" navbar item from wrapping?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

On the following navbar I am having an issue in smaller screens: The "BUTTON LINK" is wrapping under the BRAND NAME toggle. How can I prevent this behaviour?

This is the complete HTML code:

bmenu test

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background-color: #e88b17;">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem3</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="mx-auto order-0 mb-0 h3 pl-5 pr-5">
          <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="{{ url('/hmenu') }}">BRAND NAME</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn d-md-none btn-dark nav-link text-nowrap">BUTTON LINK</button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem6</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark nav-link text-nowrap">BUTTON LINK</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>

  </nav>
```

Output:

[image]

This is how I would like to appear:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs more space to fit everything on smaller devices.
So, you can remove the padding from Brand for mobile devices.

Instead of `pl-5 pr-5`, use `px-sm-5`.

```html
<div class="mx-auto order-0 mb-0 h3 px-sm-5">
```

Comment: thanks, this prevents the wrapping but the collapse responsive menu appears to the right of the screen, with the items in a strange order

Comment: Yes. I think you can ignore the `flex-nowrap`. Removing the padding will be enough in this case. Also, I'd consider using a smaller Brand image/name, maximum 90px of width.